# Conexion base de datos "mdb" con python

Tags: python, base-de-datos, mdb

por favor me podrian indicar como seria el código para conectar una base de datos "mdb" a python. Tengo una base de datos en mdb con varias tablas y quisiera realizar un QA/QC de la data en python pero no se como conectar esta tabla

Comment: Buscaste alguna libreria de python que conecte con access???? Porque basicamente tu pregunta pide eso....

Comment: Prueba con Google: "python mdb library"